# Android Emulator Orientation

Tags: android, orientation, emulation

I am new to the mobile development world. I have finished constructing an app of mine for the iPhone platform, and now I'm working on the Android version of that app. In Xcode, when the orientation of a UIViewController is switched to landscape, the emulator automatically flips to that orientation when it gets to that part of the app. Not so in Eclipse for Android. I have switched the orientation for my Android activity to landscape, but when run on the emulator, the view does not switch over. I have learned that pressing ctrl+fn+F11 activates the switch, but here is my question:

Is it possible to programmatically set up the app in a way that automatically prompts the emulator to switch over to landscape, just as it does in Xcode?

Thanks for the info!

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only way to change the orientation. To the best of my knowledge at least.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Lele, for the feedback!